# RestKit - Hydrate array of foreign keys

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, restkit

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "users": [
        {"id": "1", "name": "John Doe"},
        {"id": "2", "name": "Bill Nye"}
    ],
    "groups": [
        {"id": "1", "name": "Group1", "users": ["1", "2"]},
        {"id": "2", "name": "Group2", "users": ["1"]}
    ]
}
```

...and a Core Data model with User and Group objects. The group object has a to-many relationship (NSSet) to users.

I have found the following thread that seems to indicate that this is possible, but contains no explanation of how such a mapping is to be performed:

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/284

How do I perform this mapping such that each Group's "users" relationship is properly connected?

**Note:** I have mappings set up that correctly map the JSON users and groups to their respective Core Data objects. However, each group's "users" NSSet is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I figured this out using RestKit 0.20(pre2).

JSON needed to be changed to the following (note the attribute names in the group's users array):

```
{
    "users": [
        {"id": "1", "name": "John Doe"},
        {"id": "2", "name": "Bill Nye"}
    ],
    "groups": [
        {"id": "1", "name": "Group1", "users": [{"id" : "1"}, {"id" : "2"}]},
        {"id": "2", "name": "Group2", "users": [{"id" : "1"}]}
    ]
}
```

Then, the following mappings:

```
RKEntityMapping *userMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
userMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"id"];
[userMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"id", @"name"]];
RKEntityMapping *groupMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Group" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
groupMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"id"];
[groupMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"id", @"name"]];
[groupMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"users" mapping:userMapping];
```

And finally, the following responseDescriptors:

```
RKResponseDescriptor *userResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:classMapping pathPattern:@"/api/allthejson" keyPath:@"users" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
RKResponseDescriptor *groupResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:classMapping pathPattern:@"/api/allthejson" keyPath:@"groups" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptorsArray:@[userResponseDescriptor, groupResponseDescriptor]];
```

Then get your objects using RKObjectManager's getObjectsAtPath:parameters:success:failure method and your done!

Answer (score 1):

RestKit has many issues especially when it comes to modeling relationships. Debugging the mappings can be daunting.

Here is some code that deals with what you describe without RestKit.

```
NSArray *userArray; 
// an array populated with NSManagedObjects 
// correctly converted from JSON to the User entity

NSArray *groups = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"groups"];

for (NSDictionary *d in groups) {
   Group *g = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Group"
                  inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
   g.id = @([d[@"id"] intValue]);
   g.name = d[@"name"];
   NSArray *users = d[@"users"];
   for (NSString *s in users) {
      User *u = [[userArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
        [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id = %@", @([s intValue])]]
          objectAtIndex:0];
      [g addUsersObject:u];
   }
}
// save
```

Comment: Thanks Mundi... but is what I'm looking for impossible to do with RestKit? It seems to work just fine when hydrating many-to-one relationships. Everywhere I look seems to indicate that it is indeed possible but it is never documented how to do it.

Comment: That is my general issue with third party wrappers. They do not add any functionality and are supposed to make life easier -- until you hit a wall of undocumented problems. That is why I like to stick to the official SDK. Sorry I cannot help you with RestKit.

Comment: Thanks for your help Mundi. I managed to figure it out using RestKit and I'm happy with the result.